# Rails to Angular Migration - Load tabs Dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rails-routing, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to convert one of my RoR web pages to Angular in order to decide whether or not I'd like to migrate all of my frontend to Angular.

What I'm having trouble with is the routing - it seems the routes configured by rails always "hijack" the request and so the entire layout is loaded again instead of just the template into the ng-view div.

I tried following a few posts about this type of migration, but those either discuss a whole new environment (which is not the case for me), contradict each other (or simply use very different coding styles, which is confusing), or simply wrap up before everything is done.

What I have so far:

*Main Angular file*

```
@dashboard = angular.module('dashboard',['dashboardServices','ngSanitize'],
  ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($routeProvider,
                                           $locationProvider) ->
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard/promote.html.haml",
      controller: 'PromoteCtrl'
    })
  ]).config(["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] =
      $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  ])


dashboardServices = angular.module('promoteServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('PromoteInitData', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
      $resource('/dashboard-ng/promote-data.json', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
        create: { method: 'POST' }
      })
    ])
```

*The Promote Controller itself (currently there's really nothing there):*

```
@PromoteCtrl = @dashboard.controller('PromoteCtrl', 
  ['$scope', '$location', 'PromoteInitData'], 
  $scope, $location, $resource, PromoteInitData) ->
  # Nothing at the moment
```

*The Rails route (should be deleted?):*

```
get '/dashboard/promote', :to => 'dashboard#promote', :as => 'promote'
```

The Rails controller that will respond to the API requests is set up with "respond_to :json", each specific method returning an appropriate "respond_with" statement, but that's irrelevant as I'm not asking about the API calls between Angular and Rails (yet :) ) but rather the dynamic template loading.

The Rails layout has ng-app configured in the html tag, and I yield the content right after the ng-view div.

Any leads? I'm obviously missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `<%= yield %>` call in your template, rails will supply the html from the appropriate file (in this case `/app/views/dashboard/promote.html.haml`). Since you want angular to supply that content, you shouldn't have a `<%= yield %>` in your template, just the `ng-view`. This way rails will supply the layout html and angular can handle each page.

Comment: Does that mean I should delete the rails route as well? Or is it required? Not sure how the whole mechanism works.

Comment: No, you need the routes, otherwise you'll get a 404. Basically you want to serve the same angular page regardless of the route if it is an html request.